# Doctrine insert into Oracle 12c DB table with auto generated id

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine, dql

Im trying to insert into my database (Oracle 12c) table a new entry but im failing to do that

The following is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Divisions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="DIVISIONS")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Divisions
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DIVISIONID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="DIVISIONS_DIVISIONID_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    public $divisionid = '"SPECIFICATIONS"."ISEQ$$_79111".nextval';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DIVISIONNAME", type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     */
    public $divisionname;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="SORTORDER", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default"="1"})
     */
    public $sortorder = '1';

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ISDELETED", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    public $isdeleted = '0';

    public function getDivisionid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->divisionid;
    }

    public function getDivisionname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->divisionname;
    }

    public function setDivisionname(?string $divisionname): self
    {
        $this->divisionname = $divisionname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSortorder(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sortorder;
    }

    public function setSortorder(?int $sortorder): self
    {
        $this->sortorder = $sortorder;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsdeleted(): ?int
    {
        return $this->isdeleted;
    }

    public function setIsdeleted(?int $isdeleted): self
    {
        $this->isdeleted = $isdeleted;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

And here is my controller that is trying to "POST" and add a new Division

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Divisions;
use App\Form\DivisionsType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("api/divisions")
 */
class DivisionsController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("", name="divisions_add", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function addDivisions(Request $request)
    {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $division = new Divisions();
      $division->setDivisionname('TestDiv');
      $em->persist($division);
      $em->flush();
      return new Response(
        Response::HTTP_OK
      );
    }


}
```

when i try to call this the following Error message will appear:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO DIVISIONS (DIVISIONID, DIVISIONNAME, SORTORDER, ISDELETED) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [16, "TestDiv", "1", "0"]:

ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

For some reason no matter what i try the DivisionID column will be called.. is there a way to insert without calling some certain columns?

Or is there a way to send it as 'INSERT INTO DIVISIONS (DIVISIONNAME, SORTORDER, ISDELETED) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["TestDiv", "1", "0"]'

PS: Entity is auto generated from database

If anybody wants more info ill happily provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if anybody reaches this point and is still stuck i find kind of a work around:

I changed my Entity to look like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Divisions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="DIVISIONS")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Divisions
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DIVISIONID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    public $divisionid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DIVISIONNAME", type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     */
    public $divisionname;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="SORTORDER", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default"="1"})
     */
    public $sortorder = '1';

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ISDELETED", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    public $isdeleted = '0';

    public function getDivisionid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->divisionid;
    }

    public function getDivisionname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->divisionname;
    }

    public function setDivisionname(?string $divisionname): self
    {
        $this->divisionname = $divisionname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSortorder(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sortorder;
    }

    public function setSortorder(?int $sortorder): self
    {
        $this->sortorder = $sortorder;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsdeleted(): ?int
    {
        return $this->isdeleted;
    }

    public function setIsdeleted(?int $isdeleted): self
    {
        $this->isdeleted = $isdeleted;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Then in the Controller i added the following function:

```
private function getMaxDivisionIdNumber() {
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(u.divisionid) FROM App\Entity\Divisions u');
  $res = $query->getResult();
  return $res[0][1];
}
```

Now this function is used to get the Max id number.. so my controller would look something like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Divisions;
use App\Form\DivisionsType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("api/divisions")
 */
class DivisionsController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("", name="divisions_add", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function addDivisions(Request $request)
    {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $content = $request->getContent();
      $content = json_decode($content);
      $division = new Divisions();
      foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
        $division->$key = $value; 
      }
      $maxId = (int) $this->getMaxDivisionIdNumber();
      $division->divisionid = $maxId + 1;
      $em->persist($division);
      $em->flush();
      return new Response(
        Response::HTTP_OK
      );
    }

   private function getMaxDivisionIdNumber() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(u.divisionid) FROM App\Entity\Divisions u');
    $res = $query->getResult();
    return $res[0][1];
   }

}
```